# How to get a List of Indices from ElasticSearch using Jest

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm trying to retrieve a list of indices using Jest, but I just got as far as:

```java
Stats statistics = new Stats.Builder().build();
result = client.execute(statistics);
```

How can i retrieve the list of indices from the result? Do I have to use something else than Stats?
It would also help if someone could show me a detailed documentation of Jest. The basics are really well documented, but with the different kinds of builders I'm really lost at the moment.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of the name of indices? Or stats on the indices?

Comment: Just the names as a list of Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Get Aliases](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/90eecdb44f2daee444a6eca7aefc8b98fce5a86c/jest-common/src/main/java/io/searchbox/indices/aliases/GetAliases.java) will give you all the aliases for the indices on a node.

Comment: A short example would have been nice, as there is not really a documentation besides the code. But I got it to work nevertheless so thanks for your time.

Comment: I've never used Jest and ran into the similar problem you were having. I figured if I gave the request you would be able to figure it out much quicker than I would :P.

Comment: Thats fair ;-). If it would be too easy it would be boring.

Answer (score 4):

One can simply navigate a browser to the following URL to get the indexes available on an ElasticSearch cluster.

http://*elasticsearch.company.com*/_aliases

This will return an array of indexes and their aliases in JSON.  Here's an example:

```
{
    "compute-devzone1": { },
    "compute-den2": { },
    "compute-den1": { },
    ...
}
```

To get the list of indexes with Jest, use this code...

```
  HttpClientConfig config;
  JestClientFactory factory;
  JestClient client;
  GetAliases aliases;
  JestResult result;
  String json;

  config = new HttpClientConfig.
     Builder("http://elasticsearch.company.com").
     build();

  aliases = new GetAliases.
     Builder().
     build();

  factory = new JestClientFactory();

  factory.setHttpClientConfig(config);

  client = factory.getObject();
  result = client.execute(aliases);
  json   = result.getJsonString();
```

Use your favorite JSON processor to extract the indexes from `json`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`JestResult result = elasticSearchClient.execute(new Cat.IndicesBuilder().build());`

This will return a JSON response just like `curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?format=json"`