# How to query on latest version of elastic search index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where I have to query on the latest es index from java . Es indexes are of the pattern indexName-date . Is there a way I can do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not directly to Elasticsearch, no, as there's nothing native to do that

you'd need to grab the list of indices and then sort by date and get the latest yourself

Comment: Yeah I see that the only way forward . Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Anyone reaching here can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223714/how-to-get-a-list-of-indices-from-elasticsearch-using-jest following link to get indexes matching a regex pattern and then sort them to get the latest index .